# How can I have a minimum period greater than the rolling window in a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have multiple dataframes that have a column called `SIZE`.  I need to calculate the rolling average of the size column on each Dataframe with different rolling windows; **HOWEVER** I want them all to require `x` number of valid (non-zero) observations to have passed before generating a valid moving average, regardless of whether x is greater or less than the rolling window itself.

e.g.

```
x = 400
df1.groupby('NAME')['SIZE'].rolling(100, x).mean()
df2.groupby('NAME')['SIZE'].rolling(300, x).mean()
df3.groupby('NAME')['SIZE'].rolling(700, x).mean()
df4.groupby('NAME')['SIZE'].rolling(1000, x).mean()
```

If I were to execute the above, I receive a `ValueError: min_periods 400 must be <= window 100`

The dfs are quite large and i'm struggling to come up with a way to handle this without being incredibly slow or breaking everything.  What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't.

What you could do when `window` would be lower than `min_periods`, is to oversample and discard:

```
# for rolling 100
df1.groupby('NAME')['SIZE'].rolling(400, x).apply(lambda x: x.iloc[-100:].mean())
```

Or a double rolling:

```
s1 = df1.groupby('NAME')['SIZE'].rolling(100, x).mean()

s2 = (df1.assign(flag=df['SIZE'].ne(0))
         .groupby('NAME')['flag']
         .rolling(400, x).min().eq(1)
     )
out = s1.where(s2)
```